# How to encrypt/decrypt sent/received messages in Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, privacy

We are building a chat client (something like Whatsapp, etc.) for sending and receiving private messages. For the sake of privacy we decided to encrypt and decrypt the messages upon arrival and sending.

I figured we could use RSA private and public keys for encryption. I understand that we usually need two pairs of keys, one of which residing on the server and one on the phone. This brings up some questions which I'm asking here.

1. How to generate a key pair in android?
2. How should they be stored?
3. Do I need different key pairs for every user on the server as well as on the clients?

Please feel free to add any useful information for I am a complete newbie in security.

Comment: Just as a comment, you shouldn't use RSA to encrypt chat.  RSA should be used to establish private-private key pairs then encryption should follow using symmetric cryptography after the private-private key pairs have been exchanged via RSA (i.e. asymmetric cryptography).

Comment: @Jared Would you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: You should use TLS over the network, and possibly database-based encryption in the database.

Comment: As you may have noticed from the answer of Jared, your question is too broad. You should study cryptography and especially authentication (PKI) before continuing.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead Yeah I figured that out so far. I guess I'm gonna have to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a central server which provides certificates for each user to authenticate users (otherwise you will always be vulnerable to a man in the middle attack).  So for two users (Joe and Sally), there will be *three* certificates: 1) the certificate authenticating your central server, 2) the certificate authenticating Joe and 3) the certificate authenticating Sally.

So when Joe wants to initiate communication with Sally the following should happen:

1. Joe requests Sally's public key from the central server.
  1. Joe authenticates the server via the server's public key (by checking the digital certificate).
  2. Joe uses the server's public key to encrypt a shared secret key and then sends the encrypted shared secret key to the server.
  3. Only the server can decrypt Joe's shared secret key and thus uses this shared secret key to encrypt (via [Symmetric Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm)) Sally's public key and sends Sally's public key, encrypted via Joe's proposed shared secret key, to Joe.
  4. Joe now has Sally's public key; authenticated because it came from an authenticated server.
2. Joe sends a request to Sally to initiate communication identifying themselves as "Joe" along with a digital certificate.
  1. Sally authenticates "Joe" via the central server.
  2. Sally retrieves Joe's public key in the same way that Joe obtained Sally's public key from the central server.
3. Sally sends a shared secret key to Joe.
  1. Sally uses Joe's public key to encrypt a multi-part message which includes 1) the shared secret key and 2) a digital certificate encrypted with Sally's private key.
4. Joe receives Sally's encrypted message (which only Joe can decrypt since it was encrypted with Joe's public key).
  1. Joe decrypts the message and receives Sally's proposed shared secret key.
  2. Joe receives Sally's digital certificate, encrypted with Joe's public key, and attempts to decrypt with Sally's public key obtained previously from the central server.
  3. If Joe successfully decrypts the digital certificate, then Joe can be assured that Sally is the one who proposed the shared secret key.
  4. Joe sends an acknowledgement of the shared secret to Sally via symmetric cryptography, using the shared secret key.
5. Sally receives Joe's acknowledgement via Sally's proposed shared secret key.
6. Sally and Joe can now communicate back and forth using symmetric cryptography via Sally's originally proposed shared secret key.

So why is all of this necessary?  First, you need a "trusted" broker (that's the central server).  Otherwise you can never be sure who you are communicating with.  You may ask: why does Sally need to sign her shared secret key when only Joe can decrypt it anyway (if Sally uses Joe's public key to encrypt)?  The reason is that *anyone* can encrypt a shared secret key via Joe's public key!  Therefore if Joe receives an unsigned shared secret key, he may start communicating with a man in the middle who simply generated a shared secret key using Joe's public key.  Just as Sally needs some confirmation that Joe is the actual entity trying to communicate with her, Joe needs some assurance that the shared secret key he receives is *actually* from Sally (hence why she needs to sign with her private key).

RSA is *not safe*!!!  Given enough traffic, it *is* possible to decrypt messages encoded by RSA.  Thus, you should have a protocol in place for periodically updating public/private keys used for authentication.  This is simple for users: your central server will hold the public keys for each user.  Periodically your server should request that each user generate a new private/public key pair and send the public key to the server to be updated (this communication can be done via the previous private/public key used by each user).

It's a little more "difficult" for the central server itself.  If your central server wishes to change its private/public key (authenticating the server), then it needs to communicate with every user to make each user aware of the change.  When a user changes his/her private/public key, it's a one-to-one communication (just between the user and the server) but when the *server* wants to change *its* private/public key, it must communicate with *all* users!

**Caveat:**

I don't claim that what I proposed above is the "canonical" pattern.  What I claim, is that if you follow the above, you will will ensure both authenticity and integrity. I.e. you can be guaranteed to be communicating with the entity the central server considers to be "Joe" and "Sally" *and* you can guarantee that *only* Joe and Sally can communicate because no one, including the central server, knows the shared secret key used by Joe and Sally to communicate (except for Joe and Sally of course).

Comment: This is all wrong. Digital signatures are required at several of these steps, not just looking up a CA with a public key or sending an encrypted certificate etc. And there is never a need to encrypt a public key. That's why they're public. Have a look at how TLS does it, in RFC 2246.

Comment: @EJP What I described requires digital certificates at almost every step.  When Joe gets Sally's public key, he must first verify the central server's certificate.  When sally receives a request to communicate from Joe, she must 1) first authenticate the central server's certificate and then 2) receive Joe's public key.  Further Sally must send a signed message to Joe containing Sally's proposed shared secret key and thus Joe must authenticate Sally's certificate against the public key obtained from the central server (previously) before accepting Sally's shared secret key.

Comment: @EJP I disagree with the notion that public keys must _always_ be public.  Certainly the central server (the CA) must have a truly public key, however each user does _not_.  The CA can enforce an access policy such that Joe can talk with Sally but not to Sue.  Thus when Joe makes a request to talk to Sally, the CA returns Sally's public key whereas when Joe attempts to talk to Sue, the CA returns some kind of a deny message (not disclosing Sue's public key).  In this way some users may not have access to other users' public key--which is _not_ the case if _all_ public keys are shared.

Comment: 1. You've misread my comment. I didn't say 'digital certificates'. I said 'digital signatures'. They are required at your steps 1.1, 2.1, 3.1 (where you say 'encrypted' where you should say 'signed', and 4.2 (where you say 'decrypt' where you should say 'verify').  2. If digital certificates are being circulated, the public keys *are* public. Your solution is not secure. I suggest, again, that you look up how a real solution does it.

Comment: @EJP I agree that I did not properly use the lingo of digital signatures, but "checking the digital certificate" and "authenticating "Joe"" are the same, imo.  I was wrong when I said that Sally encrypts her digital certificate--the encryption is in the digital signature (which encrypts the manifest of the digital certificate, I believe, with Sally's private key).  The decrypt part is me describing how digital certificates work.  You read the manifest in the certificate (in plain text) then decrypt the signature with the public key--if they match then Sally has been verified.

Answer (score 2):

The most commonly used encryption/decryption technique is AES. You can find more information Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard?
You simply need to define a KEY(anything like for example: 25346483936) which will be common both at mobile as well as server end along with an IV_Vector which is required for Cryptography it will be more clear from the code below. 
Note: The length of the key must be equal to IV_Vector array size, it is 16 in the below example. Now using the encrypt method you can encrypt any information before sending it to server over a non-secure network. Similarly you can decrypt information received from server using DecryptData class.

```
public class Constants {

// encryption/decryption
public static String AES_KEY = "0366D8637F9C6B21";      
public static byte[] IV_VECTOR = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};


}



/**
 * This class is used to decrypt an encrypted string value.
 * 
 * @author kthakur
 *
 */
public class EncryptDecrytData {


    /**
     * This method is used to encrypt a string value.
     * 
     * @param text
     *          - string value to be encrypted.
     *          
     * @return result(encrypted string) as String
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     */
    @TargetApi(8)
    public static String encrytData(String text) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        byte[] static_key = Constants.AES_KEY.getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(static_key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.IV_VECTOR);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

        String result = Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.NO_WRAP|Base64.DEFAULT);
        return result;

    }

    /**
     * This method is used to decrypt a string value.
     * 
     * @param text
     *          - string value to be decrypted.
     * @return result(decrypted string) as String
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String decryptData(String text)throws Exception{

        byte[] encryted_bytes = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        byte[] static_key = Constants.AES_KEY.getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(static_key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.IV_VECTOR);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryted_bytes);
        String result = new String(decrypted);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You hard coded the secret key though...how do you securely exchange keys while, at the same time, assuring that the two parties are who they say they are?

Comment: Just showing a random AES encrypt/decrypt is not an answer, and above code does not even provide confidentiality of the messages. Completely insecure.

Comment: ehh, I still think this answer is helpful (although certainly not complete)--it does give an explanation as to how to encrypt/decrypt messages via a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: @Jared It is very likely that above will suffer from padding Oracle attacks. In general it is not wise to use symmetric crypto without authentication for transport protocols. It also doesn't show that the IV should be random for CBC. Anybody can dig up an example of symmetric crypto.

Answer (score 1):

There are many encryption/decryption algorithms such as Data Encryption Standards (DES), Playfair, etc., etc.
You may use those. And if you like, make your own algorithm. I once made a messenger app and I made my own algorithm for encryption/decryption.

You may also choose to have a symmetric or asymmetric key algorithm... Keep working, messengers have a nice scope.. :)

Comment: I would recommend the Caesar cipher myself. In that case you at least know for sure that anybody can decrypt. What about ROT13?

Comment: You may use what you like. But I recommend making your own algorithm... The one I made was based on how much and what characters you want to encrypt/decrypt. Further, it used a key to do the business. The key must be same for encryptor and decryptor. Different keys means different encrypted/decrypted messages...

Comment: That was sarcasm, which I must admit is hard to convey over the internet. One of the major rules of crypto is that you should not try and create your own.